# cannot get the pieces of ui-router to line up except in trivial cases

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I expected to be able to attach ui-routing commands to any module's config function and get a unified state hierarchy that was organized by state naming: root, root.sub, sub.detail, etc. But I seem only able to define routes in the config attached to the main app module, not in any submodules and...

Although I've tried many (all?) variations, I get no satisfaction from expecting that the following will work, presuming that my index includes: `<div ui-view="shell"></div>`.

```
var app = angular.module('shell.module', ['sub.module'])
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('shell', {
            views: {
               url: '/',
               template: '<div ui-view="area"></div>'
            }
        })

var sub = angular.module('sub.module',[]);
sub.config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('shell.sub', {
            views: {
                url: '/sub',
                template: 'satisfying content!'
            }
        })
    });
```

What appears to be true is that if the substate is not named, then the substate template replaces the root state content in index. But if both are named then the rootstate contains:

```
    <div ui-view="shell" class="ng-scope>
       <div ui-view="sub" class="ng-scope"></div>
    </div>
```

I believe this means that the first replacement succeeds, and the second (internal) replacement works, but the second replacement is not interpreted as angular syntax, just text (or html).

To me the combined experience means that the rules for ui-router are not defined except for the most trivial cases, since I seem to have read 'everything' about it, although there is not very much written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your states are not defined correctly.

the views object should contain view name as key and controller/template etc as value.

furthermore, sub-states will by default stick their content into their parent state's unnamed view. You dont have any unnamed views, so you must provide a different syntax for the views object.

I think your code should look like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('shell', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
           '' {
               template: '<div ui-view="area"></div>'
           }
        }
    })

var sub = angular.module('sub.module',[]);
sub.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('shell.sub', {
        url: 'sub/',
        views: {
            'area@shell': {
                template: 'satisfying content!'
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Also, your urls were in the wrong place and created incorrectly. subviews urls are created by prepending their parent view's url to them. So in your case the "shell.sub" url would have been `//sub` which is wrong. I fixed this.

I think you have some more doc (re)reading to do :)

Comment: This definitely worked for me! And thanks for the explanations. And it worked just as well if the view for the 'shell' state was named 'shell'.However, my bigger goal is to enable

Comment: better comment: This worked for me only if the view for the 'shell' state was named 'shell'... I'm not sure this is everything I need, but you've got me going in the right direction. Thanks,